# Redirect a folder to another domain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

Hej,

first things first: I have found two similar posts but the solutions didn't work for me. So here is problem:

I have an OpenCart multistore installation. So I run 2 shops (one in German and one in English) on 2 separate domains with the files being in one folder (web server). Before separating the German shop to it's own domain I had the German version of the shop in a subfolder like shop1.com/de/xxxx.

So now I need a htaccess redirect that forwards all German URLs to the new domain, for example:

**english-shop.com/de/page1  ->  german-shop.de/page1**

```
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# append WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L=301]

# delete trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off

# OpenCart SEO URL Settings
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
#RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?:(?:(\w{2})(?:/|\z))?(?:/|\z)?)?(?:([^?]*))? index.php?_route_=$2&site_language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It would be really great if someone could help me with this. I did find and try several solutions but nothing worked. And Google is really hating me for this :(

Thanks & best,
Derk

Comment: Please reduce your code to what is really relevant here. There is a lot of stuff in that code that has _nothing_ to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !german-shop.de
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) http://german-shop.de/$1 [R,L=301]
```

The first line prevents a redirect loop when german-shop.de/de/ is called. The second line takes the part after /de/ and put it after german-shop.de.

note: In your .htaccess you do some stuff with prepending www. and enforcing https. Maybe you need to adjust my lines to prevent extra redirects.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I'm not really used to this platform (passive user since years, but never posted a question myself).